# Extraction of first element into a list from list of tuples

Tags: python-3.x, list, tuples

I have list of tuples extracted such as the CRQ element corresponds to the related state for e.g. WAIT, MONITOR, DONE.

```
pair=[('CRQ1', 'WAIT'), ('CRQ1', 'DONE'), ('CRQ2', 'WAIT'),('CRQ2', 'MONITOR'), ('CRQ3', 'DONE'), ('CRQ4', 'MONITOR'),('CRQ5', 'DONE'),('CRQ5', 'MONITOR')]
```

My requirement is to extract CRQ elements into another list if they did not have the state 'DONE'.

Hence, the list should look like:

```
list=[CRQ2,CRQ4]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `OrderedDict` to combine your records by keys ('CRQ1', 'CRQ2', etc.) and after that you can retrieve keys according to your statement:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

adict = OrderedDict()

for obj in pair:
    adict.setdefault(obj[0], []).append(obj[1])

print([obj[0] for obj in adict.items() if 'DONE' not in obj[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using simply list comprehension:

list = [val[0] for val in pair if val[1] != 'DONE']

Comment: Hi, this gives me ['CRQ1', 'CRQ2', 'CRQ2', 'CRQ4', 'CRQ5']. However, this is not my requirement. As CRQ1 has 'DONE' state in one of the iterations, it should not be a member of this list. Also, as the first state of CRQ5 is 'DONE' I am looking to 'break' the flow and iterate over the next CRQ elements.

Comment: As I mentioned, the list should have only those CRQ's which did not have the state 'DONE' anywhere. In pairs, only CRQ2 and CRQ4 fall in this category

Answer (score 0):

The are two ways to do this:

1. Procedural way:

```py
pair=[('CRQ1', 'WAIT'), ('CRQ1', 'DONE'), ('CRQ2', 'WAIT'),('CRQ2', 'MONITOR'), ('CRQ3', 'DONE'), ('CRQ4', 'MONITOR'),('CRQ5', 'DONE'),('CRQ5', 'MONITOR')]
arr = []

for cr, val in pair:
    if val != 'DONE':
        arr.append(cr)
```

2. Declarative way (using list comprehensions)

```py
pair=[('CRQ1', 'WAIT'), ('CRQ1', 'DONE'), ('CRQ2', 'WAIT'),('CRQ2', 'MONITOR'), ('CRQ3', 'DONE'), ('CRQ4', 'MONITOR'),('CRQ5', 'DONE'),('CRQ5', 'MONITOR')]
arr = [cr for cr, val in pair if val != 'DONE']
```